# Laravel 5.2 : Fetch records against logged in user id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am fetching records in controller :

```
$tasks = Task::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);

return view('todo',compact('tasks'));
```

But it returns null.

And `Auth::user()->id` returns `2` Which is Okay.

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually retrieve the record. What you have is an instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`, but not the actual record(s) associated with the query.

To tell Eloquent to fetch the data, you need to use either `get()`.

Like:

`$tasks = Task::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();`

As a side note, you can simplify your query to be:

`$tasks = Task::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();`

Furthermore, on your `User` model, you could do this:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class) // make sure you use the full namespace here or use at the top of User.php
}
```

And then you can simply do:

```
$tasks = auth()->user()->tasks;
```

This is a Relationship in Eloquent as explained [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).